# Urban Code deploy: How to get the credentials of the user under which the process is running?

Tags: rest, http, urbancode

I have a process where i am using the **Send HTTP Call** step.
The step needs username and password to invoke the URL. I want these to be the credentials of the user that is running the process.
How do I supply these to the Send HTTP Call step?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the request.user.id property to get the user ID, but you can't get the password of the user that requested the process.